# Leo's deterministic reduction for Earley Parsing

Tags: algorithms, context-free, parsers

I am trying to build an Earley parser using the [Wikipedia pesudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser) as a base, with [Aycock's fix](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5b27/7a3f9a9f5250939f334e282d1393971722a9.pdf) for epsilon rules as follows:

```
def predict(self, column, symbol, state):
    # original predict
    for alternative in grammar[symbol]:
        column.add(a new state corresponding to alternative)
    # Aycock fix
    if nullable(symbol):
        column.add(state.advance())
```

And [Leo's optimization for right recursion](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030439759190180A) using the explanation [here](http://loup-vaillant.fr/tutorials/earley-parsing/right-recursion) for further insight.
I am able to understand how to parse Right Recursive grammars with it. However, I am confused when it comes to using it to parse non-right recursive grammars.
For example, here is a grammar that can parse an example string `aa`

```
    <start> := <A>
    <A>     := <A> + 'a'
    <A>     := \epsilon
```

Without the deterministic reduction from Leo, the Earley items constructed (pipe indicates the dot) are as follows:
The parenthesis is in this format (starting column, earley set).

```
char: _ column[0]
<start>:= | <A>(0,0)     #1) init
<A>:= | <A> a(0,0)       #2) predict from 1
<A>:= |(0,0)             #3) predict from 1
<start>:= <A> |(0,0)     #4) epsilon complete from 3
<A>:= <A> | a(0,0)       #5) epsilon complete from 3 


char: a column[1]
<A>:= <A> a |(0,1)       #6) scan a from 5
<start>:= <A> |(0,1)     #7) complete A from 1 (start col of 6)
<A>:= <A> | a(0,1)       #8) complete A from 2 (start col of 6)


char: a column[2]
<A>:= <A> a |(0,2)       #9) scan a from 8
<start>:= <A> |(0,2)     #10) complete A from 1 (start col of 9)
<A>:= <A> | a(0,2)       #11) complete A from 2 (start col of 9)
```

According to Leo,

> **Definition 2.1**: An item is said to be on the deterministic reduction path above $ [A \rightarrow  \gamma., i] $ if it is $ [B
> > \rightarrow \alpha A ., k] $ with $ [B \rightarrow \alpha . A, k] $
>   being the only item in $ I_i $ with the dot in front of A, or if it is
>   on the deterministic reduction path above $ [B \rightarrow \alpha A .,
> > k] $. An item on such a path is called *topmost* one if there is no
>   item on the deterministic reduction path above it.

(I am assuming that $ [B \rightarrow \alpha A ., k] $ is also in $ I_i $.)

The completer is as follows:

```
def complete(self, column, state):
    detred = self.deterministic_reduction(state)
    if detred:
        column.add(detred)
    else:
        for st in (matching states in start column of state):
            column.add(st.advance())
```

## column 0

So, when it processes item (3) `<A>:= |(0,0)` in `column[0]` for completing, it finds both item (1) which obeys the restriction for a single item with dot before `<A>` and the corresponding item (4) with dot after. Hence, it considers (4) on the deterministic path. This does not change anything for column[0]. However, things change for column[1].

## column 1

When it processes (6) for completing, it again finds (1) and item (4), and hence (4) is considered a parent in the deterministic path. Hence, it saves a copy (4) to the column[1] **rather than completing it traditionally in earley**. This means that the item (8) `<A>:= <A> | a(0,1)` from the original Earley parse **never gets created**, which means no item for accepting the next `a` in column[2] (which should have been added to column[2] by scanning of this item), and the parsing fails.

So, my understanding of *deterministic reduction* bye Leo is somehow faulty. Where have I gone wrong?

I have read up on all materials I could get on Leo's optimization, but still unclear what I have missed. I think the item (4) should not be a parent because it is not a previous instance of the recursive rule in item (6). However, nothing in Leo's paper seems to explain how I can exclude such instances from the deterministic path.

If it helps, the complete self contained implementation is [here](https://gist.github.com/vrthra/5119b747ee536f7c5533379247a55760).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem: Essentially, I misunderstood the definition. It says that

> it is [B→αA.,k] with [B→α.A,k] being the only item in Ii with the dot
>   in front of A, or if it is on the deterministic reduction path above
>   [B→αA.,k].

Which should be interpreted as `[B→αA.,k]` should be considered to be created corresponding to `[B→α.A,k]`. The basic idea which seems to be elided in Leo's paper but given in [Grune et al. (2008)](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9780387202488) is that, the deterministic reduction is basically simply an eager completion with all intermediate results thrown away. With this change, the parser works correctly.

(The "Parsing Techniques A Practical Guide" by Grune et al. from 2008 is the book I refer to here.)

Comment: _Grune et al. (2008)_ it not a sufficient citation, Grune published many things that year. What is the paper title?

Comment: @orlp I have added the title and a link.